# How to set image path in image tag using PHP

Tags: php, image

I need one help.I need to set the image path after fetched from DB inside image tag using PHP.I am explaining my code below.

```
$getcustomerobj = $dbobj->getNewsData($id);
div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12">
<span class="input-group-addon ndrftextwidth text-left">Upload Image :</span>
<input type="file" class="filestyle form-control" data-size="lg" name="newsimage" id="newsimage" onChange="javascript:addImage(event,'img','disImage');">

</div>
<div id="disImage" style="display:none;"> 
<div class="input-group bmargindiv1 text-right col-md-12" >
<img src="uploads/"'.<?php echo $getcustomerobj->image ?>.' name="pro" id="img" border="0" style="width:50px; height:50px; border:#808080 1px solid;" />
 </div>
```

Here i am getting the data from DB using `$getcustomerobj` but unable to display it.Please help me.

Comment: Insert ```$getcustomerobj = $dbobj->getNewsData($id);``` between <?php ?> and add < to second line, and ```src="uploads/<?php echo $getcustomerobj->image ?>"```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it wrong. The path should be inside the `"`s. Try with -

```
<img src="uploads/<?php echo $getcustomerobj->image ?>" name="pro"...
```

would work.

Comment: check again i have also div display none initially.

Comment: Is that the actual code? If yes then there are more errors!

Comment: its not full code.I already said here i have initially image tag will not display.

Answer (score 0):

your code `<img src="uploads/"'.<?php echo $getcustomerobj->image ?>.' name="pro" id="img" border="0" style="width:50px; height:50px; border:#808080 1px solid;" />` change to

```
<img src="<?php echo 'uploads/'.$getcustomerobj->image ?>" name="pro" id="img" border="0" style="width:50px; height:50px; border:#808080 1px solid;" />
```